# Creating A select element and if statement to display different href

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to create a drop down menu and then based on selection display a clickable link to book time with each Customer service manager ... sorry for the awful code below i pieced it together from very old knowledge and google

\\

```
</select>

<button onclick="message()">book a time </button>

<SCRIPT>

function message() {

var s = document.getElementById('item1');
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
let bookt;
if (item1 == 1) 
     { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= <a href= "httpslink">Book Kim </a>;
     }
      
else if (item1 == 2) 
    { bookt="ibrahim link"; }
    
else if (item1 == 3) {
    bookt= <a href="https link"></a>;}


else if (item1 == 4) {
    bookt="Steff Link";}


}
</SCRIPT>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

\\

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do it:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select')
const links = ['https://google.com/', 'https://apple.com/', 'https://microsoft.com/']
var selectedItem = links[0]
function update() {
const item = parseInt(selectedItem)
document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = `<a href=${links[item]}><button onclick="update()">book a time</button></a>`
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<select id='select' onchange='selectedItem = this.value;update()'>
<option selected hidden>Choose a person</option>
<option value='1'>Person 1</option>
<option value='2'>Person 2</option>
<option value='3'>Person 3</option>
</select>
<div id='link'><button>Please choose an option!</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `links` array contains the links to each page that you would like to send the user to for the selected person, who is stored inside of the dropdown menu.